# c++ 17 filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator() gives error no such directory on mac but works on windows

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, c++17, std-filesystem

**Configurations**

- macOS: 10.15.5
- xcode: 11.5
- clang: 11.0.3
- Project is set to c++17

I am new to macOS and trying to solve a simple problem..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    for(const auto& p: fs::recursive_directory_iterator("data/"))
        cout << p.path() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives me error (tried on xcode, clion and cmake) -

```
uncaught exception of type std::__1::__fs::filesystem::filesystem_error: 
filesystem error: in recursive_directory_iterator: No such file or directory [data/]
```

**ISSUE**
Here data folder is created by me manually or some time automatically. Random files will be generated in it (sub directories files too), I need path and name of all those files.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**
**This code works perfectly fine**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
 
int main()
{
    fs::create_directories("sandbox/a/b");
    std::ofstream("sandbox/file1.txt");
    fs::create_symlink("a", "sandbox/syma");
    for(auto& p: fs::recursive_directory_iterator("sandbox"))
        std::cout << p.path() << '\n';
    fs::remove_all("sandbox");
}
```

Comment: The snippet should work as expected, and the exception message is pretty clear - are you sure you have a `./data` directory inside the working directory from which you invoke the executable?

Comment: still getting same error.... filesystem error: in recursive_directory_iterator: No such file or directory [./data/]

Comment: Try compiling that on the command line, or figure out what the working directory is that XCode uses to run the executable. It's this working directory where `data` must exist.

Comment: data folder is right beside main.cpp

Comment: if you don't remove `sandbox` does it actually at where you expected?

Comment: @apple apple I tried it right now and... it does not, there is no sandbox folder after commenting remove_all line. That means it is executing from somewhere else

Comment: There is no sandbox folder in whole project folder... I understood what it  means but I need a way so that I can access folder beside code files even in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three options:

1. In XCode, go to `Product` - `Scheme` - `Edit Scheme`, then choose the `Run` target in the left column, switch to `Options` and use the `Working directory` to point to the directory in which you want the target executable to be run. This is where your `data` directory must exist for the program to succeed.
2. Figure out the actual working directory XCode is using. Create the `data` directory there.
3. Specify an absolute path, as in

   ```
   for(const auto& p: fs::recursive_directory_iterator("/my/absolute/path/data/"))
   ```

The difference to the working snippet that you posted is that it creates a new directory relative to XCode's working directory. Which can then obviously be found, contrary to the manually created `data` directory next to `main.cpp`.

Comment: I will try it now and I think this will work... but I don't think this will work for cmake..
As there will be no way to set working directory... 

Why mac does not start searching beside from main.cpp or is there any way to get relative address of main.cpp so I can use it

Comment: It does work with option 1, option 2 will work but worthless, option 3 is static What if I need to access file dynamically in runtime... Like access parent folder of main.cpp

Comment: Then require one command line argument and let this be the base path that you wish to traverse. In the `Edit Scheme` settings, there is an option to specify command line arguments to be passed to your executable.

Comment: In the end, your executable should work independently of sources like `main.cpp`. The source directory has nothing to do with the executable (debugging aside). That's why keeping a clean (no build artifacts) source directory is always good. Hence XCode doesn't mess with your sources, and instead sets up  a separate directory for running the executable.

Comment: I understand you want me to pass source directory path as argument to executable and then add it to all the paths. But I can't digest this thing that macOS does not have a standard way to access source file folder right out of box.